# Issue installing postgres with npm

Tags: windows, node.js, postgresql, npm, node-gyp

I'm having issues installi [pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) via npm on my windows machine.

It complains about python but I've added python as env. variable in many ways to no avail.

These are all the ways I tried declaring the env. var.

- `C:/Program Files/Python`
- `"C:/Program Files/Python"`
- `C:/Program Files/Python/python.exe`
- `"C:/Program Files/Python/python.exe"`

Here's the error:

```
D:\Projects\GitHub\inmotion>npm -g install pg
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/1.0.12
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/1.0.12
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/-/generic-pool-1.0.12.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/-/generic-pool-1.0.12.tgz

> pg@0.8.3 install C:\Users\Guzza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pg
> node-gyp rebuild || (exit 0)


C:\Users\Guzza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pg>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable ""C:/Program Files/Python"", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:95:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:59:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Guzza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pg
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.6.1
gyp ERR! not ok
pg@0.8.3 C:\Users\Guzza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pg
└── generic-pool@1.0.12
```

Comment: I'd guess it doesn't like spaces. Install Python to `C:\Python` and try again.

Comment: Have you tried setting the path to use \ instead of /?  This is Windows, after all.

Comment: @Joe Windows *almost* always accepts `/` in place of \ and has since win98 or older. Sadly, it's that *almost* that'll bite you; in particular, anything that treats `/` as a command-line flag (eg `/?`, `/h`, etc, just like unix uses `-`) will choke. Apps that don't have issues in command-line processing will work fine; the kernel doesn't care if you use '/' or \ AFAIK.

Comment: I'd accept kichik comment if it was an answer 'cause that did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try `C:\PROGRA~1\Python` as your environment entry, presumably for the `PYTHON` environment variable. If the [shortname](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/01/27/362105.aspx) for `Program Files` is different on your install, check with:

1. Start->run or hold the windows-key and press R
2. `cmd.exe` **enter**
3. `cd "Program Files"` **enter**
4. `dir`

If I recall correctly the shortname should be listed alongside the long name for directories.

Please report this as a bug to whoever maintains the software you're using, they need to fix their code to handle spaces in paths correctly.

Comment: why does npm require Python ?

Comment: @entropy No idea... ask them.